# Is the space of continuous maps $Top(X,Y)$ between two topological spaces compact if $X$ is?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, and we consider $Y^X$, i.e. the space of maps from $X$ to $Y$ with the compact-open topology.  If $X$ is compact then can we say anything about $Y^X$?

Thanks!
Jon

Comment: [Generalizations of Arzelà-Ascoli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzela-Ascoli#Compact_metric_spaces_and_compact_Hausdorff_spaces) at Wikipedia

Comment: Is there any added assumption on $Y$? Is it $T_1$, or regular, etc.

Comment: If $X$ is the one pointed space (compact), then $Top(X,Y) \cong Y.$

Answer (score 9):

Suppose $X$ is a one-point space. Then $Y^X$ is naturally homeomorphic to $Y$, so is not compact unless $Y$ is.